# How to concatenate two Array keys?

Tags: php, html, arrays, function

I would like to know if there is a way to convert two Array keys into one Array key?

As an example the Array would look like:

```
[0] => '12345' 
[1] => 'New'
[2] => 'York'
```

how can I combine `[1] => 'New'` and `[2] => 'York'` into `[1] => 'New York'`?

All I was found is `array_merge` that combines two Arrays. Even on how to concaternate two Array keys I could not find anything.

Thanks alot.

Comment: There is no built in function for this. Just concatenate them yourself and then modify your array accordingly.

Comment: "Even on how to concaternate two Array keys I could not find anything" so how should this work? can you give me a hint?

Comment: $array[1].=' '.$array[2];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
$data = array(12345,"New","York");
echo concat($data, array(1,2)); //New York
```

//or

```
$data = array(12345,"New","York");
print_r(concatArray($data, array(1,2)));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => New York
)
```

Function Used

```
function concat($array, $keys , $glue = " ") {
    $values = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
    return implode($glue, $values);
}


function concatArray($array, $keys, $glue = " ") {
    $last = null;
    foreach ( $array as $key => &$value ) {
        if (in_array($key, $keys)) {
            if ($last === null) {
                $last = $key;
                continue;
            }
            $array[$last] .= $glue . $value;
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint ;)

```
$new = $array[1] . ' ' . $array[2];
$array[1] = $new;
unset($array[2]);
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for the existences tho. This would at least throw like four warnings if the keys don't exist ;)

Comment: That's why this is a hint ;)

Comment: Now I get it. Thats quiet simple but pedestrian. Thanks.